# Insert multiple row in excel VB code required?

Tags: vba

```
Sub insertMultipleRows()
'code disables excel while macro runs'
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rowcount As Integer
rowcount = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="how many rows do you want to insert" & ActiveCell.Row & "?", Type:=1)
'handle error for instances when row count may be negative or zero'
If rowcount <= 0 Then End

Rows(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & ActiveCell.Row + rowcount – 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

LOL. Spent ages scratching my head on this one. As I saw it there was no reason why this code wouldn't work. I copied your code into VBA and the below line should up red:

```
Rows(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & ActiveCell.Row + rowcount – 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

For the life of me I couldn't see why and it didn't make any sense.

I deleted the line and manually typed it and everything worked fine! What the ....

Decided to paste the line from above under the line I typed and this is what I got:

[image]

Curiouser and curioser! I pasted both line into Text Comparer https://text-compare.com/ and there it was! You're using the wrong minus Character. What you're using is the  ASCII 150 Character instead of the standard ASCII 45 character.

Here's the proper code:

```
Rows(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & ActiveCell.Row + rowcount - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```